# Writing multiple streams sequentially in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am consuming data from kafka through spark structured streaming and trying to write it to 3 different sources. I want the streams to execute sequentially as the logic(in writer) in stream2(query2) is dependent on stream1(query1). What is happening is the query2 get executed before query1 and my logic breaks.

```
val inputDf = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("assign"," {\""+topic+"\":[0]}") 
  .load()

 val query1 = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST (partition AS INT)","CAST (offset AS INT)","CAST (timestamp AS STRING)")
df1.agg(min("offset"), max("offset"))
  .writeStream
  .foreach(writer)
  .outputMode("complete")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 minutes"))
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc1).start()


 //result= (derived from some processing over 'inputDf' dataframe)

  val query2 = result.select(result("eventdate")).distinct   
 distDates.writeStream.foreach(writer1)
 .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 minutes"))
 .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc2).start()


 val query3 = result.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("orc")
  .partitionBy("eventdate")
  .option("path", "/warehouse/test_duplicate/download/data1")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc)
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 999999999)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 minutes"))
  .start()

  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
  result.checkpoint()
```

Comment: You might want cricket_007 to assess.